# Redirecting website page from domain to subdomain

Tags: php, apache, redirect, dns, subdomain

I need your help

I moved my website from domain

> http://www.example.com to http://oldwebsite.example.com

I have lots of pdf document with link

> http://www.example.com/documents/news/test.pdf

Whenever a user click on the above link, I would like to automatically redirect all the PDF file.

> http://www.example.com/documents/news/test.pdf
> to
> http://oldwebsite.example.com/documents/news/test.pdf

---

> http://www.example.com/documents/news/onetest.pdf
> to
> http://oldwebsite.example.com/documents/news/onetest.pdf

I am using an apache server with PHP.

Thanks for your help

Tairon

Comment: If your links had been coded correctly as `documents/news/test.pdf` etc then you would not have this issue

Comment: I know, but it was done by third party. I am looking for a quite and better solution than changing all of them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this redirect old website to new website by .htaccess file. You need to update you .htaccess file in your old website folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy, just use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). There are thousands of tutorials on the web.

Comment: Really only worthy of a comment, dont you think? Otherwise its a link only answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was in doubt... The title on "Add a comment" says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements."